# CSS fluid width for a center column

Tags: css

I have nested divs like this (pseudo code..)

```
<div0>
    <div1></div1>
    <div2>fluid width</div2>
    <div3></div3>   
</div0>
```

given that **div0, div1 and div3** have fixed width, it is possible to give a style to the center **div2** so always has fluid width (of course based on div0 main wrapper)?

Comment: div0 has fixed width... so div2 = div0-(div3+div1) thats not fluid?

Comment: I don't get it neither - how can you have fluid width div2 "based on" fixed width div0?

Comment: I think what camelCase is trying to do is let the width of div2 adjust itself to fill the space after specifying the width for div0, given the dimensions for div1 and div3.  This would be useful if you are setting up a fixed-width page template and you want to adjust the page with without having to touch the widths of the nested div's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

how could div 2 possibly have a fluid width if div0 does not. You could set div 2 to position fixed but this would reult in a unusable mess. Anyway I assume it was an error and you want div 0 and 2 to be fluid.

yes it is possible

just set the with of div1 and 3 as padding left and right on the container. And use a negative margin (or left/right value) to set them in the right place.

Float the divs 1 2 and 3 left.

*edit*

here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/meo/H2LPJ/1/
well its a little more complicated then my explenation.

Oh and i assume your content is in div2 so it would more semantic to plcae this div first in the content: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/

Comment: i can't use absolute position so i can't use left/right values, can you be more clear?

Comment: dont need position absolute, relative does the trick also. Just a minute i am doing a JS fiddle example

Answer (score 0):

Good multi-column layouts examples: [Float-less CSS layout](http://tjkdesign.com/articles/css-layout/no_div_no_float_no_clear_no_hack_no_joke.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I came up against this problem and whilst the agreed solution is Ok it relies on float and weird margins which are not so good when you want more than one row.

I suggest that whilst the flex css directive is still way too bleeding edge for production yet you could use  display:table; to give you what you (and I) needed.

here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/richardhulbert/q1cgrb79/)

```css
.results {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.datarow {
  display: table-row;
}
.datarow div {
  display: table-cell;
}
.left {
  background: blue;
  width: 150px;
  color: white;
}
.center {
  width: 100%
}
.right {
  background: red;
  width: 120px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="results">
  <div class="datarow">
    <div class="left">This box has a fixed width of 150px</div>
    <div class="center">This box is flexible</div>
    <div class="right">This box has a fixed width of 120px</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps someone